# Can't figure out SUM formula

Tags: google-sheets

This is the formula I am trying to do:

```
=SUM(D9:D14)*2.55,
    (D16:D23)*3.90,
    (D25:D32)*6.40,
    (D34:D41)*10.60, 
    (D43:D46)*10.50,
    (D48:D51)*6,
    (D53:D59)*3,
    (D61:D64)*1.8,(D66:D69)*6
```

I need the sum of each set * different amounts and totaled on one line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that you are doing something wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling the `SUM` function before each range, as you did for the first one, and then adding them together, if you want the sum? ie. `sum(D9:D14)*2.55 + SUM(D16:D23)*3.90 + ...`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should also work

> =SUM(SUM(D9:D14)*2.55,SUM(D16:D23)*3.90,SUM(D25:D32)*6.40,SUM(D34:D41)*10.60,SUM(D43:D46)*10.50,SUM(D48:D51)*6,SUM(D53:D59)*3,SUM(D61:D64)*1.8,SUM(D66:D69)*6)

Answer (score 0):

Very slightly shorter version:

```
=SUM(D9:D14)*2.55+SUM(D16:D23)*3.9+SUM(D25:D32)*6.4+SUM(D34:D41)*10.6+SUM(D43:D46)*10.5+SUM(D48:D51,D66:D69)*6+SUM(D53:D59)*3+SUM(D61:D64)*1.8
```